# Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT query

Tags: graphql, knex.js, strapi

I am following a tutorial for [strapi](https://blog.strapi.io/cooking-a-deliveroo-clone-with-nuxt-vue-js-graphql-strapi-and-stripe-dishes-list-part-3-7/) and am stuck at a part where I query for dishes belonging to a restaurant. I'm sure everything is set up properly with a one(restaurant) to many(dishes) relationship defined but the query doesn't work. I've traced it to the actual query which is:

```
query {
    restaurant(id: "1") {
    id
    name
    dishes {
      name
      description
    }
  }
}
```

which returns an error when I run it in playground. The query doesn't show any issues while I write it and doesn't allow me to write anything like:

```
query {
    restaurant(where:{id: "1"}) {
    id
    name
    dishes {
      name
      description
    }
  }
}
```

My database is mysql and the two tables look like this:

```
mysql> describe dishes;
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| name        | varchar(255)  | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| description | longtext      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| price       | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| restaurant  | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| created_at  | timestamp     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                             |
| updated_at  | timestamp     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> describe restaurants;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| name        | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| description | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| created_at  | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                             |
| updated_at  | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

These tables where auto generated by strapi.

The full error in playground is this:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT query: select `restaurants`.* from `restaurants` where `restaurants`.`id` = ? limit ?",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "restaurant"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "Error: Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT query: select `restaurants`.* from `restaurants` where `restaurants`.`id` = ? limit ?",
            "    at QueryCompiler_MySQL.toSQL (/Users/redqueen/development/deliveroo/server/node_modules/knex/lib/query/compiler.js:85:13)",
            "    at Builder.toSQL (/Users/redqueen/development/deliveroo/server/node_modules/knex/lib/query/builder.js:72:44)",
            "    at /Users/redqueen/development/deliveroo/server/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:37:34",
            "From previous event:",
            "    at Runner.run (/Users/redqueen/development/deliveroo/server/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:33:30)",
            "    at Builder.Target.then (/Users/redqueen/development/deliveroo/server/node_modules/knex/lib/interface.js:23:43)",
            "    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)",
            "    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)",
            "    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)",
            "    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:120:23)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data":
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was a bug with the alpha.v20 and alpha.v21 versions of strapi. A bug fix has been published to solve it, an issue thread on github is [here.](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/pull/2687)